# Rich Snippet not showing in Google Search result page when I searched by keyword

Tags: google-search, google-rich-snippets

When I search like this:

```
site:https://ecomincomeblueprint.com/funnelsblueprint/clickfunnels-review-vs-leadpage-and-samcart-is-the-pricing-scam/
```

it's working. But when I search same URL by my keyword, it's not showing the star rating.

**Showing star rating**

[image]

**Not showing star rating**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off topic, as the tag specifies.

Answer (score 0):

The site: search is a special case and will show rich snippets as ling as they are marked up technically correctly.

However, Google has further quality checks before it will show those rich snippets for real searches. Based on the guidelines, the sort of things they may check could be:

- Is the review visible on the page
- Is it a review of a single thing
- Is it the official page for the review
- Is the rating clearly shown on the page
- Does the markup match what is shown on the page
- Is the website trusted